# Writing the CDF of the exponential distribution in terms of another variable

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I have a standard exponential CDF:

$F_X(x) = $
\begin{cases}
1-e^{\lambda x},  & \text{x $\ge$ 0} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

$ Y  = ((X-2)^2-1)^2\\X = 2\pm(1\pm \sqrt{Y})^{1/2} $

If someone could please edit my equation to show + or - better, thank you.

I want to write the CDF of

$F_Y(y) = ?$

This is not straight forward because multiple values of Y map into the same value of X. (I think I'm saying that right) Therefore, I have to add the probabilities for instances where one value of Y, lets say 0.5, will produce 4 different values depending on if you are taking plus/minus. I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this right however, this is what I have managed to pierce together:

$F_Y(y) = $

\begin{cases}
4-e^{\lambda x_1}-e^{\lambda x_2}-e^{\lambda x_3}-e^{\lambda x_4},  & \text{0 $\le$ Y $\le$1} \\
2-e^{\lambda x_1}-e^{\lambda x_3},  & \text{Y > 1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Where $x_i$ is equal too:

$x_1 = 2+(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\\x_2 = 2+(1-\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\\x_3 = 2-(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\\x_4 = 2-(1-\sqrt{y})^{1/2}$

In other words, I'm trying to add the intervals up where the Y variable exists for values of X. Since between [0,1], y can map into four possible x values, I need to add those four mappings up in the CDF. I would appericate some help. TY

In response to some comments, I am posting further work I have done.

Plotting the function g(x):

[image]

The red line represents y and all of the graph below that line is where the inequality has to be written for: ( I am trying to show between points #1,#2 and #3 & #4.

$ 2-(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\le x \le 2-(1-\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\\2+(1-\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\le x \le 2+(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}$

Are these the two inequalities that show the areas where x is less than some y?

$ if y > 1 \\P(2-(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\le x \le 2+(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}$

Comment: `\pm` `\ge` `\le`

Comment: \pm worked but \ge did not

Comment: Of course, one needs `$...$`

Comment: I thought since the entire brace was enclosed $$ would not be needed. Thanks for information.

Comment: Actually `\text{x ≥ 0}` there should read `x\ge 0`. Likewise further below.

Comment: Just use definition of $F_Y(y)$ directly:
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(((X-2)^2-1)^2\le y)$$ and proceed from here solving the inner inequality.

Comment: On the other hand, your approach can be used to find $f_Y$, not $F_y$, but with an important correction: $$f_Y(y)=\sum_{x:g(x)=y}\frac {f_X(x)}{g'(x)}$$
given that $Y=g(X)$.

Comment: So your saying $P(X \le 2\pm(1\pm \sqrt{y})^{1/2}) = F_Y(y)$ ? But how do you handle the $\pm$?

Comment: @budder No. I am saying you need to solve $((X-2)^2-1)\le y$ as an inequality, not an equation.

Comment: @ A.S. okay. I guess that's where I am lost. When I think of solving an inequality, I typically think the only difference is I have to flip the inequality sign when multiplying or dividing by a negative number. Could you refer me or explain how to solve this as an inequality?

Comment: @budder Hint: Solution to $X^2\le y$ is $-\sqrt y\le X \le \sqrt y$ for $y\geq 0$ and no solutions otherwise. Something similar for solving $y\le X^2$.

Comment: I added more to my question (above) which elaborates on these: $ 2-(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\le x \le 2-(1-\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\\2+(1-\sqrt{y})^{1/2}\le x \le 2+(1+\sqrt{y})^{1/2}$

Comment: Your first inequality doesn't make sense since $LHS\ge RHS$. You made a plot that tells you that solutions to $g(X)\le y$ for $y> 1$ is a single interval $[r_1,r_2]$ and for $0\le y\le 1$ the solution is union of $[r_1,r_2]\cup [r_3,r_4]$ where $r_i's$ are roots of $g(X)=y$ ordered from smallest to largest - including multiplicities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30655/discussion-between-budder-and-a-s).